# How to parse a regex to entire spark dataframe and not each column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to check if there is any formulae column inside a csv file. So I have constructed a regex and want to parse to entire dataframe.

I have a solution but that does it column by column, I feel it will hit the performance for large datasets.

```
 val columns = df.columns
 import spark.implicits._
 val dfColumns = columns.map{name =>
  val some = df.filter($"$name".rlike("""^=.+\)$"""))
  some.count()>0
 }
 val exist = dfColumns.exists(x=> x)
```

Comment: does my answer actually answer your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply same methods to the whole dataframe.

Instead you can optimize a little bit your code.

```
val df = spark.read.csv("your_path").cache // Cache the dataframe to avoid re reading
import spark.implicits._

df.columns.map{
  name => df.filter($s"$name".rlike("""^=.+\)$""")).isEmpty // Use isEmpty to avoid counting everything when it is not needed.
}.exists(identity)
```

Be aware that filter is usually pushed at the top of the catalyst plan, so if you do something else than just reading, the `cache` might not result in better performances (but `isEmpty` will always do)

PS: `isEmpty` is from Spark 2.3, if you do not have the right version, you can use `df.limit(1).count > 0` Which will `limit` before counting, and will increase your performances.